# window.onload does not override prototype function

Tags: javascript

When I try to create an HTTP logger for a website, I need to overwrite the window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open function to receive all the HTTP Requests and log them. However when I try to overwrite the function in the window.onload function, the code doesn't function.

The function including window.onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
   let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
   window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(
      method,
      url,
      async,
      user,
      password
   ) {
      console.log(this);
      oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
      this.addEventListener("load", function() {
         let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         console.log(json);
      });
   };
};
```

This doesn't work how I want it to because it doesn't log the HTTP Requests made. However when I post the following code in the terminal it works:

```
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(
   method,
   url,
   async,
   user,
   password
) {
   console.log(this);
   oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
   this.addEventListener("load", function() {
      let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(json);
   });
};
```

I expect the first window.onload function to overwrite the window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open method and that it logs all the HTTP Requests to the console.